# How do you run unit tests in Python in the REPL?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to develop unit tests in Python using unittest from the Standard Library, and I want to try things out in the REPL. If I have the following code loaded

```
import unittest

class TestTrivial(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_trivial(self):
        self.assertEqual(1 + 1, 2)
        self.assertFalse(2 + 2 == 5)
```

Then I can evaluate the following in the REPL:

```
unittest.main()
```

That spits out:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK

Process Python finished
```

The problem is it killed the REPL. How do I run it without quitting the REPL?

Comment: "The problem is it killed the REPL" Why is this a problem, exactly? You aren't going to be automating stuff typed into the REPL anyway. You can run `unittest` as a module (see the documentation) from the command line, and end up back at the command line.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Exiting the current process could be a problem in situations other than testing things out in the REPL. It's a reasonable question with a simple answer.

Comment: I would take another approach and use the debugger in the unit test. add this line anywhere in the test `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. When you run your tests it will stop where you added the line from there you can use all the debugging tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `exit=False` as an argument:

```
unittest.main(exit=False)
```

`unittest.main` isn't actually a function; it's just another name for `unittest.main.TestProgram`, whose `__init__` method ultimately calls a `runTests` method, which ends with these lines:

```
    if self.exit:
        sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
```

Setting `self.exit` to `False` prevents `sys.exit` from being called.

This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#loading-and-running-tests) (see the end of the section), but not easily found.